# How auto link new static library when rebuild exe with no source file change?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

```
EXE: my_app
SOURCE FILE: app.cc
EXTERNAL_STATIC_LIB: liba.a, libb.a
```

what I want:
`app.cc` not change, `liba.a` changed
relink `liba.a` when rebuild `my_app`

Comment: Re-link the object files and library files to form a new executable.

Comment: Rebuild your project(Clean+build).

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please show what you tried up to now and explain why it did not work as expected. Alternately, you could take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score -3):

Static libraries are not getting linked with the exe, instead during building it will become the part of .exe. You may need to do the make clean and replace your static libraries (.a) and then do the make, Your .exe will refer the changed static libraries.

Comment: I would say that "linking" is exactly the process of "combining all parts into an executable". So even static libraries,  which are in basis simply an archive of object files,  get linked into an exe.

Comment: @Andre,  Linking is not exactly the process of "combining all parts into an executable". what about .so and .dll? I mentioned it explicitly because the same is not with dynamic linked libraries like .so and .dll.

Comment: "In essence", it is the combining of all parts: It is the process of resolving all undefined symbols/references and tying the calls together (and some technical details). And it does not matter really for the linker whether the symbols reside in a static or dynamic library or in object files. Suddenly claiming that it is only linking when you use a dynamic library is simply incorrect.

Comment: @Andre It is required to mention here because the static library referred code is becoming the part of the .exe or .exe only contains that, but in case of .so simply replacing the .so will work, no need to rebuild anything if function signature are not changed. Hope you can understand why I mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: @Sanjeev yes, the static library is into `exe`.I mean is: it will rebuild `app.o` when `app.cc` changed, but not do same thing with `.a` changed